# How can I get a file from Docker container running inside GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hier is my pipeline script:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind
docker-run-master:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY  
  script:
    - docker run -d --name poser $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello
```

This image $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello generates a Word file, how can I rich it without using of runner (everything inside gitlab)?

I have the idea to push it back to the same repo, but how? Or something else, I need any solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets would help you if you need to get the file while job's running

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Also you can fetch the image from the registry (docker pull {registry_url}/liskior/hello after login (docker login {registry_url}) and run it locally.
For example, you can create your own image based on this image writing your own Dockerfile, or while running mount the volume with the file to your host machine, or simply get into this container and fetch the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, with this code you will be able to get a file.txt inside of a running container and it will be available to download on the pipeline artifacts.

```
image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind
docker-run-master:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY  
  script:    
    - IMAGE_ID=$(docker images -q $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello) # get image id from the last image built    
    - docker run -d --name $CI_PIPELINE_ID -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello
    - docker wait $CI_PIPELINE_ID    
    - CONTAINER_ID=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" $CI_PIPELINE_ID) # Get the container_ID
    - docker container cp $CONTAINER_ID:/file.txt $CI_PROJECT_DIR/file.txt  # copy the file from the container to the project folder    
    - docker stop $CI_PIPELINE_ID
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" # see documentation to see other types of rules
  tags:
    - runnner 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - file.txtHere is your answer, with this code you will get a file.txt inside of the container and put it available in the pipeline results to download.

image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind
docker-run-master:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY  
  script:    
    - IMAGE_ID=$(docker images -q $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello) # get image id from the last image built    
    - docker run -d --name $CI_PIPELINE_ID -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $CI_REGISTRY/liskior/hello
    - docker wait $CI_PIPELINE_ID    
    - CONTAINER_ID=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" $CI_PIPELINE_ID) # Get the container_ID
    - docker container cp $CONTAINER_ID:/file.txt $CI_PROJECT_DIR/file.txt  # copy the file from the container to the project folder    
    - docker stop $CI_PIPELINE_ID
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" # see documentation to see other types of rules
  tags:
    - runnner 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - file.txt
```